# I want to hide the form and show a written success message as well as reload the page with a hash value

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a form and as I submit I want to hide the form and show a written success message when I submit it. I want to also be able to reload the page with a hash value.

I made this function, which works but I feel like it'll give me some reload problems as the form appearing again and success message dissapearing. The form tag contains the `onSubmit="submissionmMessage()`

```
<script>
    function submissionMessage() {
        window.location.hash = "#success";  
        document.getElementById("successMessage").style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById("form").style.display = 'none';
 </script>
```

```
<div>
    <p style="display:none;" id="successMessage"><strong> Success!</strong></p>
</div>
```

It works for hiding the showing the message but I feel like there could be room for errors?

also if I put in the `"window.location.hash = "#success"`
and the success url as the url with the `#sucess` at the end will it be counter-intuitive?

Comment: Please refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: This is actually not completely a client-side issue if you aren't using AJAX or a variant of. In your server code you will want to redirect back to the page with the hash then after that detect if the hash tag exists using `document.location.hash` and hide the form and show message.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
   #success {
    display: none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <p id="demo" class="font-effect-shadow-multiple"></p>

  <script>
   function submissionmMessage() {

    /*

    Get Response from SERVER using AJAX.

    */

    document.getElementById("success").style.display = "block";


   }
  </script>

  <div id="success">Your Form has bee Submitted.</div>

  <form id="form" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submissionmMessage();">

   <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />

  </form>

 </body>

 </html>
```